# i can't declare or use java swing objects

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

i made a java swing programm using Apache netbeans yesterday.before i shut down my pc everything was running correctly. when i opened the project today it gave me errors for all swing objects.
[image: i even get errors in the declaration]

it's only swing objects though, sql objects and others like int, Long are still correct.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of initializing the objects as javax.swing.JTable bet1; for example, I'd try importing javax.swing.*; at the top and initializing the objects as JTable bet1; instead.